# How to share datastores between multiple exchange servers?

Tags: exchange, load-balancing, exchange-2003, migration

I have an Exchange 2003 box that is seriously overstressed.
I want to transfer its duties to a new and faster box.

I don't cannot suffer downtime, so I have to do this stuff live.

Here's what I plan to do:

- Install Exchange 2003 on the new server
- Set up the new server, so it will accept requests from users for their mailboxes
- I want to do as little manual set up as possible, because that 'll eat up my time and is too error prone
- Than I want to transfer my datastores one by one to the new server and have those users (once the datastore in the new server is up and running) to get their data from the new server (without them noticing)
- I don't have to transfer **all** the datastores, some of them need to stay on the old box (because I'm still waiting for extra HD space to arrive from the supplier)

What steps do I need to follow to do this?
The new box has never seen this domain before, the old exchange server is not the DC, we have a dedicated DC.

Comment: "I want to do as little manual set up as possible, because that 'll eat up my time and is too error prone" - **Good Luck With That**

Answer (score 2):

There are points in your question that don't make sense, but might I susgest you use the procedure in the following MS article on moving Exchange to new hardware while keeping the same server name. This will simplify the process and reduce some of the risk and complexity that you'd have if you take any other course of action.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997176(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: Glad to help...